# Blackberry - Small Up Down Arrow Button

Tags: user-interface, graphics, blackberry, custom-controls

i want to create 2 buttons for blackberry which look like this...[alt text http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/3285/button2.jpg](http://img260.imageshack.us/img260/3285/button2.jpg)

and the second one inverted of the above

i wanted to do this without using images (for efficiency) and the buttons should appear only when there is focus on them and dis sapper when focus goes off..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArrowButtonField as a Field extention:

```
class ArrowButtonField extends Field {
    public static final int TYPE_UP = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_DOWN = 1;

    private int mBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
    private int mFillColor = Color.CRIMSON;
    private int mWidth = 20;
    private int mHeight = 12;
    private int mArrowType = TYPE_UP;

    public ArrowButtonField(int bgColor, int fillColor, int arrowType) {
        super(FOCUSABLE);
        setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
        setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mArrowType = arrowType;
        mBackgroundColor = bgColor;
        mFillColor = fillColor;
    }

    // cancel theme border and background style
    protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
    }

    protected boolean navigationUnclick(int status, int time) {
        fieldChangeNotify(0);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onUnfocus() {
        invalidate();
        super.onUnfocus();
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.clear();
        graphics.setColor(mBackgroundColor);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        if (isFocus()) {
            graphics.setColor(mFillColor);
            int xc = 10;
            int y1 = 0, y2 = 0, x2 = xc - 9, x1 = xc + 9;

            switch (mArrowType) {
            case TYPE_DOWN:
                y1 = 11;
                y2 = 1;
                break;
            case TYPE_UP:
                y1 = 1;
                y2 = 11;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            int[] xPts = new int[] { x1, x2, xc };
            int[] yPts = new int[] { y1, y1, y2 };
            graphics.drawFilledPath(xPts, yPts, null, null);
        }
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return mWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return mHeight;
    }

    protected void layout(int width, int height) {
        setExtent(mWidth, mHeight);
    }
}
```

Classes for Up and Down Arrow:

```
class UpArrowButtonField extends ArrowButtonField {
    public UpArrowButtonField(int backgroundColor, int fillColor) {
        super(backgroundColor, fillColor, TYPE_UP);
    }
}

class DownArrowButtonField extends ArrowButtonField {
    public DownArrowButtonField(int backgroundColor, int fillColor) {
        super(backgroundColor, fillColor, TYPE_DOWN);
    }
}
```

Sample of use:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {
    UpArrowButtonField arrowUp;
    DownArrowButtonField arrowDown;

    public Scr() {
        arrowUp = new UpArrowButtonField(Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
        arrowUp.setChangeListener(this);
        add(arrowUp);
        arrowDown = new DownArrowButtonField(Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
        arrowDown.setChangeListener(this);
        add(arrowDown);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == arrowUp) {
            Dialog.inform("UP");
        } else if (field == arrowDown) {
            Dialog.inform("DOWN");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Field object, then implement a custom paint() method that draws the geometric shapes you require.  Take a look at the [Graphics](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html) class - your field's paint method is passed the Graphics object and you can make use of that to draw filled rectangles, polygons, etc.